# I have to find the sum of the series if $0<x<c<1$ for $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (n^3x^n) $

Tags: power-series

I have to find this using either a power series or Taylor series method.
The furthest I got was splitting it to $a_n = n^3$ and $f_n = x^n$.

Comment: what denotes $c$ in your sum?

Comment: To start, differentiate $\sum x^n$, then multiply by $x$.

Comment: Hint: $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n = f(z) \implies \sum_{n=0}^\infty na_n x^n = x\frac{d}{dx} f(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint : Define
$G[\lambda]=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}e^{i\lambda n}_{}x^{n}_{}=\frac{1}{1-x e^{i\lambda}}$ and note $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}n^{3}_{}x^{n}_{}=\frac{\partial^{3}_{}}{\partial(i\lambda)^{3}_{}}G[\lambda]\Big|_{\lambda=0}$.

Answer (score 0):

The sum $S"'= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}n^3 x^n$ you can think about it as the third derivative of   $S= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n$ so knowing that $S=\frac{1-x^n}{1-x}$ then you do the rest.

Answer (score 0):

One may use the following form of [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)):
$$ \frac{1}{(1-x)^{k+1}}=\sum_{n\geq 0}\binom{n+k}{k} x^n, $$
repeated differentiation or the following approach.

$q(n)=n^3$ is a third degree polynomial in the $n$ variable. By denoting through $\delta$ the forward difference operator, $(\delta p)(n)=p(n+1)-p(n)$, we have that $\delta^4 q(n)\equiv 0$, hence
$$ (1-x)^4 \sum_{n\geq 0}n^3 x^n $$
is a polynomial in the $x$ variable with degree $\leq 3$, since
$$ (1-x)\sum_{n\geq 0} r(n) x^n = \sum_{n\geq 0}r(n) x^n-\sum_{n\geq 0}r(n) x^{n+1}=r(0)+\sum_{n\geq 0}(\delta r)(n)x^{n+1}. $$ 
By computing in a explicit way the product between $(1-x)^4$ and $0^3+1^3 x+2^3 x^2+3^3 x^3$ we get
$$ (1-x)^4\sum_{n\geq 0}n^3 x^n = \left(x+4 x^2+x^3\right) $$
and we are done: $\sum_{n\geq 0}n^3 x^n=\frac{x(1+4x+x^2)}{(1-x)^4}.$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** $n^3=n(n-1)(n-2)+3n(n-1)+n$, so
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty n^3x^n
&=x^3\sum_{n=0}^\infty n(n-1)(n-2)x^{n-3}+3x^2\sum_{n=0}^\infty n(n-1)x^{n-2}+x\sum_{n=0}^\infty nx^{n-1}\\
%&=\frac{6x^3}{(1-x)^4}+\frac{6x^2}{(1-x)^3}+\frac x{(1-x)^2}\\[3pt]
%&=\frac{x+4x^2+x^3}{(1-x)^4}
\end{align}
$$